# how to find and execute a file in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I am trying to us the find command and -exec to -execute a file file when found but it doesn't seem to work. here is some code:

```
 ssh $i find $DIRECTORY -name "version.sh" -exec sh {} \;
```

I am getting the error no arguments for -exec

thanks!

Comment: If the file contains a valid shebang line, you don't need the `sh`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Your* side gets a semicolon, but the *other* side doesn't.

```
... \\\;
```

Comment: +1 To be more elaborate; your shell expands metacharacters before the command is executed. If you want the `ssh` command line to contain shell metacharacters, you need to quote or escape them.

Comment: The ssh command does see the semicolon, but the shell on the other side consumes it as a command separator.

Comment: Yeah, it's the backslash which needs treatment, like you show.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable version could be:

```
ssh $i "find $DIRECTORY -name version.sh | xargs -r sh"
```